# Plotting points on python basemap yields runtime error

Tags: python, sqlite, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I try to (in python 3.6) plot points (airports) from a database (sqlite and basemap modules) on a global map according to latitude and longitude coordinates. However, my code plots the points as a separate figure from the map and a runtime error that says: *RuntimeError: Can not put single artist in more than one figure.*  I am not sure what I am doing wrong:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("flights.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from airlines limit 5;")
results = cur.fetchall()
print(results)
coords = cur.execute(""" select cast(longitude as float), \
                     cast(latitude as float) from airports;""" \
                     ).fetchall()

m = Basemap(projection = 'merc', llcrnrlat =-80, urcrnrlat = 80, \
            llcrnrlon = -180, urcrnrlon = 180, lat_ts = 20, \
            resolution = 'c')

m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawmapboundary()

x, y = m([l[0] for l in coords], [l[1] for l in coords])
m.scatter(x, y, 1, marker='o', color='red')
```

The error I get is the following:

```
RuntimeError: Can not put single artist in more than one figure
```

Comment: The dataset 'flights.db' can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a2wax843eniq12g/flights.db?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite last lines as

```
lons = [l[0] for l in coords]
lats = [l[1] for l in coords]
x, y = m(lons, lats)

m.scatter(x, y, 1, marker='o', color='red')
plt.show()
```

[image]